# How can I create an enum value dynamically in Scala 3 macros?

Tags: scala, metaprogramming, scala-macros, scala-3

I'm creating an enum value dynamically.  I have a type of the enum (not the object itself) and a string representing a valid value, e.g. "Red" for Color.Red.

```scala
// T is Color (enum).  I've discovered the valueOf() method lives in the companion object
val sym = TypeRepr.of[T].classSymbol.get.companionClass

// Try to invoke the valueOf() method on the enum with the value, enumValue ("Red")
Apply(Select.unique(New(TypeIdent(sym)), "valueOf"), List('{ enumValue }.asTerm)).asExprOf[T]
```

It compiles but is deeply unhappy when run.  Doesn't like New there, which makes sense because we don't "new" objects.

What's the proper way to invoke valueOf dynamically in a macro?

Comment: What is the code that you want to generate? Also print the generated code so we can compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum Test:
  case A

object TestMacros: {
  def printAST(using quotes: scala.quoted.Quotes): Unit = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    println('{ Test.valueOf("A") }.asTerm.show(using Printer.TreeStructure))
  }
}

// call printAST insome inline def
```

prints:

```
Inlined(Some(TypeIdent("TestMacros$")), Nil, Apply(Select(Ident("Test"), "valueOf"), List(Literal(StringConstant("A")))))
```

after removing `Inline` garbadge:

```
Apply(Select(Ident("Test"), "valueOf"), List(Literal(StringConstant("A"))))
```

To construct this tree (your problem seem to be `Ident`) I guess we can use:

```
val sym = TypeRepr.of[Test].typeSymbol
Apply(Select.unique(Ref(sym), "valueOf"), List(...))
//                  ^ Ref can be used to turn a symbol of singleton type to Term
```

Usage of `Ref` is the same whether you construct anything dynamically or in compile time.

When I need to handle sealed hierarchies "statically" I use the following apprach:

1. obtain a list of all children types

```
def extractRecursively(sym: Symbol): List[Symbol] =
  if sym.flags.is(Flags.Sealed) then sym.children.flatMap(extractRecursively)
  else if sym.flags.is(Flags.Enum) then List(sym.typeRef.typeSymbol)
  else if sym.flags.is(Flags.Module) then List(sym.typeRef.typeSymbol.moduleClass)
  else List(sym)

extractRecursively(TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol).distinct.map { subtype =>
  subtype.primaryConstructor.paramSymss match {
    // subtype takes type parameters
    case typeParamSymbols :: _ if typeParamSymbols.exists(_.isType) =>
      // we have to figure how subtypes type params map to parent type params
      val appliedTypeByParam: Map[String, TypeRepr] =
        subtype.typeRef
          .baseType(TypeRepr.of[A].typeSymbol)
          .typeArgs
          .map(_.typeSymbol.name)
          .zip(TypeRepr.of[A].typeArgs)
          .toMap
         
      val typeParamReprs: List[TypeRepr] = typeParamSymbols.map(_.name).map(appliedTypeByParam)
      subtype.typeRef.appliedTo(typeParamReprs).asType
    // subtype is monomorphic
    case _ =>
      subtype.typeRef.asType
}
```

2. turn `Type`s into `Expr`s

```
// subtype: Type[?]
//
// put the subtype into implicit scope with some name, e.g.:
//
// type B <: A
// given B: Type[B] = subtype.asInstanecOf[Type[B]]

val B = TypeRepr.of[B] // type of A's subtype
val sym = B.typeSymbol

// case object B extends A
def isScala2Enum = sym.flags.is(Flags.Case | Flags.Module)
// Scala 3 enum's parametersless case is NOT case object
// but: val B = new A {}
def isScala3Enum = sym.flags.is(Flags.Case | Flags.Enum | Flags.JavaStatic)
// Java: enum A { B; }
def isJavaEnumValue: Boolean = TypeRepr.of[B] <:< TypeRepr.of[java.lang.Enum[?]] && !sym.isAbstract

if (isScala3Enum || isJavaEnumValue) then Some(Ref(sym).asExprOf[B])
else if isScala2Enum then Some(Ref(sym.companionModule).asExprOf[B])
else None
```

3. handle cases when some subtypes are `case class`es (create None for the code above)

(Actually, Scala 3 macros treat Java enums the same as Scala 3 enums without any parenthesis, so  `|| isJavaEnumValue` is kinda redundant - you could remove it and it should still works with Scala 2's `sealed` hierarchy of `case object`s, Scala 3's `enum`s AND Java `enum`s).

As you can see in both cases, dynamical and statical, when I need to access case object/parameterless case in Scala 3's enum/Java's enum/companion object's method I am using `Ref <: Term` to turn `Symbol` into `Term` (and it will be `Ident` internally).